# Restriction regarding multiple namespaces in trial version of Codefluent?

Tags: codefluent

I have not yet bought the ultimate but i'm really consider it, however i have problems.

I have the ultimate trial version and it seems that it is not possible to use multiple namespaces. 
Is there a restriction due to trial version?
When using multiple namespaces i get compiler errors in the "bom"library project.

Comment: There are entities restrictions (50 usually) but nothing related to namespaces. Plus when you have licence issue, there are also license messages explaining the problem. You should give us more details about the errors you get.

Comment: I renamed my surfaces to having the "root" namespace in it's name, e.g Orders.OrderProcess and Orders.Customer and now it's working. Could it be that i had relations between my surfaces that were all "root" surface?